# Ruby 1.9, return array if keys include a particular object

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

Code:

```
@albums = @genres.each_with_index { |item,key|
  if item.keys.include?('Albums')
    break
  end
 }
```

This should be returning the Albums array (the @genres object is a huge multidimensional JSON response)

I reckon this is what I get for trying to code while being sick... or just simply doing things wrong... either way, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `#detect` (or its synonym `#find`):

```
@albums = @genres.detect { |item| item.key?('Albums') }['Albums']
```

EDIT | Also note that you can provide an argument to `break` just like you can do with `return`, if you want to break and return a specific value.

Comment: Shouldn't that be item['Albums']? Also, does detect work properly with hashes, because map doesn't with them, only arrays. My point is be careful which enumerable methods you're using.

Comment: I assumed `@genres` was an Array, so the `detect` returns a Hash, and then I'm just chaining the key lookup onto that Hash.  The OP was using each_with_index, but never using the key. `item.key?('Albums')` is the correct way to ask if `item` has a key called 'Albums', even if the value stored is `nil`.

Comment: I interpreted the phrase "huge multidimensional json response" as being a hash, so I guess maybe we need some clarification.